# selecting decimal float in mysql query

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT distinct t4.value,t1.`date_created`, t5.value, t6.value
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` AS t0
JOIN wp_rg_lead AS t1 ON t1.`id` = t0.`lead_id`
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail AS t2 ON t0.`lead_id`=t2.`lead_id`
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail AS t3 ON t0.`lead_id`=t3.`lead_id`
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail AS t4 ON t0.`lead_id`=t4.`lead_id`
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail AS t5 ON t0.`lead_id`=t5.`lead_id`
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail AS t6 ON t0.`lead_id`=t6.`lead_id`
WHERE t1.`date_created` > '2014-01-01'
AND (t2.field_number = 31 AND t2.value= "somevalue")
AND (t3.field_number = 111 and t3.value="yes")
AND (t4.field_number = 24)
AND (t5.field_number = 73)
AND (t6.field_number = 2.60)
AND t0.`form_id`=5
```

the t6.fieldnummer field value is FLOAT.
How to convert (into what) the 2.60 value in my query as it would match with the value in the database? I'm facing this problem only with decimal value.

Comment: What is the data type of `t6.field_number` and what is the value you are trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do floating-point number comparison is to first decide on an acceptable tolerance for differences between the numbers and then do the comparison against the tolerance value. For example, if we agree that floating-point numbers should be regarded the same if they are same within a precision of one in ten thousand (0.0001), the comparison should be written to find differences larger than the tolerance value:

```
   ABS(t6.field_number - 2.60) <= 0.0001
```